# Kernel crash when calling Block

Tags: list-manipulation, crash

Ive made a module to expand a list by reflections and translations. Here is the block.

```
 makeBZ001[x_] := Block[{rt1, , rt2, rt3, dat = x, temp1, temp2, temp3, rm, tempfull,
 full, rtt, res},
 rt1 = ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}];
 temp1 = dat;
 temp1[[All, ;; 2]] = rt1[temp1[[All, ;; 2]]];
 rt2 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}];
 temp2 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1]];
 temp2[[All, ;; 2]] = rt2[temp2[[All, ;; 2]]];
 rt3 = ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}];
 temp3 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2]];
 temp3[[All, ;; 2]] = rt3[temp3[[All, ;; 2]]];
 tempfull = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2, temp3]];
 rm = RegionMember[Polygon[{{0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, -1.0}, {-1.0, 0.0}}]];
 full = Pick[tempfull, rm[tempfull[[All, ;; 2]]]];
 rtt = RotationTransform[\[Pi]/180 45];
 res = full;
 res[[All, ;; 2]] = rtt[res[[All, ;; 2]]];
 res
 ]
```

Now, I've tested the code without the `Block` and it works as expected, no problems. However, when I call it after making a block it causes the kernel to crash.

```
test = makeBZ001[data];
```

Any ideas about whats causing this issue?

Vesion is `(*11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)*)`

Here is an example of the data: [sampledata](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YDdHOeOcNEr55W6C0KOfd7roi-jrxuF5)

After the data runs through all the procedures and its plotted it looks like this,
     [image]

**Edit**
I've tried the code on my desktop and it runs fine, seems to be some sort of issue with the memory, Im guessing.

Comment: Could you provide an example of input and the expected output? It is also a good idea to say what your `$Version` is when it comes to questions of the kind. On my machine (`"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`) there is no crash when `RandomReal[1, {5, 3}]` is supplied as input.

Comment: Thank you for quick cooperation :) But the sample data file you provided shows only one cell with "csv" inside :(

Comment: @Anton.Sakovich fixed! The sample data is working now.

Comment: I've manage to isolate the problem to the `Pick` command. I even switch the order to make all reflections and rotations firsts, and this works well. However it crashes when doing `Pick` in the last step.

Comment: Are you saying that `data = Import["j11.csv"]`, then `makeBZ001[data];`, will crash the kernel? I.e., it beeps, the notebook doesn't change, and the In[...] counter resets to 1? I can't reproduce that in M11.3 / macOS 10.13.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: No crash for me either, v11.2@Win10x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works in my version 11.3

```
makeBZ001[x_] := 
 Block[{rt1, , rt2, rt3, dat = x, temp1, temp2, temp3, rm, tempfull, 
   full, rtt, res}, rt1 = ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}];
  temp1 = dat;
  temp1[[All, ;; 2]] = rt1[temp1[[All, ;; 2]]];
  rt2 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}];
  temp2 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1]];
  temp2[[All, ;; 2]] = rt2[temp2[[All, ;; 2]]];
  rt3 = ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}];
  temp3 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2]];
  temp3[[All, ;; 2]] = rt3[temp3[[All, ;; 2]]];
  tempfull = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2, temp3]];
  rm = RegionMember[
    Polygon[{{0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, -1.0}, {-1.0, 0.0}}]];
  full = Pick[tempfull, rm[tempfull[[All, ;; 2]]]];
  rtt = RotationTransform[\[Pi]/180 45];
  res = full;
  res[[All, ;; 2]] = rtt[res[[All, ;; 2]]];
  res]
data = Import["C:\\Users\\Alexander Trounev\\Desktop\\j11.csv"]

p = makeBZ001[data]

ListPlot3D[p, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image: fig1]